# Is there a way to delete an Azure cloud service (web role) and leave a DNS CName record in it's place?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record

We currently have two cloud services (web roles) running in Azure. They correspond to the version 1 release of our product and the version 2 release. The dns names that got assigned by Azure are something like:

ver1app.cloudapp.net and ver2app.cloudapp.net.

For version 2, we have a proper DNS CNAME record that points to ver2app.cloudapp.net. All new customers are using the custom domain name and getting to ver2app.

Unfortunately, we have legacy users in the field that are hardcoded to the url ver1app.cloudapp.net. This is a custom IOT type device that doesn't follow http redirects so I can't do something simple like Url Rewrite.

My goal is to completely retire the ver1app so I don't have to keep maintaining it. I think a clean solution to our problem would be if we could delete ver1app.cloudapp.net but leave a CNAME that pointed to ver2app.cloudapp.net. I don't see a way to do this with Microsoft owning the cloudapp.net domain. Is there a way? Is there a different way to accomplish this that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1):

Would an IIS rewrite rule help? This [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/Documentation/Articles/cdn-cloud-service-with-cdn/) talks about CDN but it shows rewrites.  You might ask on SO if you need help with the rewrite rule.  See also http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference

Comment: Nope. As stated, the device won't follow redirects so a url rewrite is out.

Comment: In that case, could you stand up a proxy on DNS1 that would pass through requests to DNS2 for your service?

Comment: I'm not suggesting the device do the rewrite, set up the site to do the redirect, or are you saying that it wont follow the redirect sent by the website?

Comment: Jim b - yes, the device will not follow an http redirect sent by the server like a browser will.

Comment: Proteus - I don't control the DNS, Microsoft does. But I think you meant to say make ver1app a proxy for ver2app. If so, yes, that's an option I've considered. It means we would still have to deploy and maintain a cloud service at ver1app.cloudapp.net but it could be very minimal, stripped down app. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: So from my research a URL rewite doesn't have to redirect, it can also (essentially) server as a reverse proxy.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference.  I would also suggest you query SO to see if this method would work.  It seems to me it would as its all server side, unlike a standard 301,302

Answer (score 0):

The domain name "cloudapp.net" is controlled by Microsoft. Deleting the Cloud Service will cause the domain name to be released, and eventually it won't resolve to anything, the only way for you to keep using the domain name is to use a Cloud Service.

If your old devices doesn't understand URL Redirect, or JQuery redirects, or anything redirect, then you're pretty much screwed. keep using the old App Ver 1 VM until you migrate all of your users to App Ver 2.

Comment: Yes, understood. I'm mostly conducting due diligence - making sure there's no way to get Microsoft to add the record or some other option I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, since `cloudapp.net` is not yours to use however you want, what you may actually want to do is deploy the new version so that it's accessible on `ver1app.cloudapp.net` and associate your custom domain with that.

Clearly not what you had in mind initially but that would at least allow your legacy clients to continue working and having the new domain name in place as well.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, Håkan. However, I neglected to mention that we have users hard coded to ver2app.cloudapp.net as well so the problem still exists. However, there are many fewer users pointed to the ver2app url so this may be the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @GregEnslow That certainly complicates the situation further.